# Why is it recommended to delete interaction terms "as a chunk"?

Tags: interaction, model-selection

In [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/11080/9162) it was discussed that when terms are being deleted for the purposes of model simplification, it's best to delete terms "by chunk". That is, in an x1 * x2 * x3 * x4 scenario we'd contemplating deleting the fourth order term, and if we did that we might consider removing all the third order terms, and so on.

I often see people ignoring this advice and removing particular interaction terms at a level. For that reason, I asked why it was recommended to remove interaction terms as a chunk.

@frank-harrell [wrote here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11009/including-the-interaction-but-not-the-main-effects-in-a-model#comment299391_11080) that

> If you have a completely pre-specified order that was not determined
>   by looking at the data, then you may be OK to do that. In general you
>   will have co-linearity and multiplicity problems when making multiple
>   decisions using multiple P-values.

Can anyone provide some more detail about why these problems occur? When, if ever, is it valid to delete individual interaction terms at a particular level?