# What happens when you add a factor as a predictor in R?

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

Let's say I have two models:

`lifeexpF~group + log(ppgdp) + group:log(ppgdp)`

`lifeexpF~log(ppgdp) + group:log(ppgdp)`

group is a factor

I understand that the first model is the general model, and it gives a different slope and intercept for each group. For the second model, I think the slopes are all different, but the intercepts are the same; however, I'm not quite sure as I am very new to regression and R.

Comment: What is your question?  You might be interested in the answers at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11009, especially that by [Frank Harrell](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/11080/919).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what adding "group" to the model does.

Comment: Although your question is not very clear, the difference between both models is the inclusion/exclusion of a main effect term from a model with interaction consisting of the term.
In other words, you have included the main effect term for "group" in the first model which is the "advisable"/"right" thing to do if the term is part of a significant interaction term. Refer to the link @whuber provided to see a detailed explanation

Comment: I read through the responses in the link, and most answers say that the main effects term should be included if there's an interaction that uses the main effects term. I guess my question is: what happens to the model when the main effects term is omitted even though it is part of an interaction?

Comment: Yes, the intercepts are the same in the second model.  Specifically, the expected value is the same for all groups when ppgdp=1.  That's probably a pretty odd constraint on the model, and so I think you would have to have a very good reason to use the second form of the model rather than the first.