# the differences of interaction mark in lme4

Tags: lme4-nlme

I want to make a model including interaction term of factor 1 and factor 2.

But i don't understand difference of models
 like

```
    m <- lmer(RT ~ fac1 * fac2 + (1+fac1*fac2|subject), data = df)
```

and

```
    m<- lmer(RT ~ fac1 : fac2 + (1|subject) + (fac1:subject) + (fac2:subject), data = df)
```

which one is right for making interaction term
 and what is difference between them ?

thanks for reading !

Comment: Check `?formula` or [one of many tutorials](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-formula-tutorial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colon `:` indicates a multiplicative term (an interaction).

The asterisk `*` automatically includes both the interaction and the main effects: `a * b` is interpreted the same way as `a + b + a:b` (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567421/vs-in-r-for-modelling)

You typically should start with the asterisk `a * b` or the full expression (`a + b + a:b`), but there may be occasional exceptions -- see [Including the interaction but not the main effects in a model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11009/including-the-interaction-but-not-the-main-effects-in-a-model)