# How to compute and interpret interaction term between continuous variables that have negative values?

Tags: regression, interaction, continuous-data

I was wondering about the computation and interpretation of interaction terms of continuous variables that are used in a multiple regression.
Normally, one would mean-center (or z-standardize) the two constituent continuous variables and then multiply these values to create the interaction term. Then all three variables (continuous variable A, continuous variable B, and the interaction term AxB) can be used as regressors in a multiple regression.

However, I am a bit confused regarding negative values in the continuous variables (that result for instance from mean-centering/z-standardization). If one has only positive values, then two high positive values in both A and B would result in a high value in AxB (e.g., 10 x 10 = 100), and lower values in A and B would result in very small values in AxB (e.g., 0.2 x 0.2 = 0.04). This would result in a regressor where low values in the interaction regressor indicate low values of both continuous variables, and high values indicate high values of both.

BUT: With negative values, this relationship appears to change fundamentally. Let's say we have now two low values of both continous variables that are negative, then the interaction term would be a high positive value (e.g., -10 x -10 = 100). But this has the same value as both values in the positive domain (e.g., 10 x 10 = 100). Shouldn't they get different weights in order to differentiate effects of high/high vs. low/low? In the same fashion, high/low and low/high receive equal weights (e.g. -10 x 10 = -100; 10 x -10 = -100) and cannot be differentiated. That confuses me a lot. Or do I miss something here?

Best, Stefan

Comment: You are overlooking the fact that (with few exceptions) the variables themselves are included in the model as well as a constant term.  Thus, the model is fitting a restricted form of quadratic polynomial (a bilinear function)--and this does not "change fundamentally" when the variables are recentered.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11009 for extensive discussion.