# How to read interaction coefficients in logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic, interaction, interpretation

How do i read `age:gender1`?

Gender1 is male.

```r
Call:
glm(formula = cardio ~ gender + age + gender * age, family = binomial, 
     data = CVtrain)

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -1.060e+01  3.328e-01 -31.843  < 2e-16 ***
age           5.164e-02  2.108e-03  24.492  < 2e-16 ***
gender1       4.146e-01  1.758e-01   2.358 0.018379 *  
age:gender1  -8.018e-03  3.283e-03  -2.442 0.014597 *
```

Comment: How would you read them for a linear model?

Comment: Would it be "The effect on the presence of `cardio` of 1 unit increase in age is exp(-8.018e-03) = 99% more for those that are male as compared to females" ??

By that measure, `gender` shouldn't be included at all.

Comment: There is no exponential in a linear model. How would you interpret the interaction in a linear model?

Comment: The effect on the presence of cardio of 1 unit increase in age is 8.01e-03 less for those that are male as compared to females

Comment: So then that’s the effect on the log-odds, right?

Comment: See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/471851/7071).