# Measure the influence of variable A on variable B's impact on variable C

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression

I have three variables. I know that variable B has a correlation with variable C. I'm interested in whether variable A impacts variable B's relationship with variable C, and not on whether variable A directly impacts variable C.

Multiple regression seems not appropriate for this question as this would be measuring each of variable A and B impact on C, which is not what I want.

My other thought was to simply multiple A by B and then correlate with C in order to determine whether this has increased / decreased the correlation.

Any other ideas to determine whether A impacts B's relationship with C?

Or thoughts on why either of the above is or isn't useful?

Answer (score 4):

The best approach is to combine both any "direct" effect of A along with the interaction represented by the product of A times B in a multiple regression. The general form for such a model, as it's represented in R syntax, would be:

```
C ~ B + A + A:B
```

That model (if you use the standard treatment coding) will provide:

- an intercept--the value of C when A and B are both at their reference
  values (0 for a continuous predictor),
- individual coefficients for A and B, representing how much C changes
  with respect to each of them *when the other predictor is at its
  reference level*, and
- a coefficient for the interaction A:B (which is just the product of A
  times B for continuous predictors), representing how much the
  individual associations of each of A and B change as the other one of
  the pair changes.

For this to be most interpretable, you should include A in your model [in addition to the interaction coefficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/11080/28500) even if you don't care specifically about its individual association with C.