# Verification and visualization of survival analysis

Tags: data-visualization, survival

I performed some experiment with two clones of cells `CloneType` `red` and `green`. The task was to determine sensitivity of these clones to some class of drugs. To do so I used 3 members of this drug class: `DrugType` `A`,`B` and `C` in different concentrations. I have the following R code to estimate the sensitivity of cells:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library('tidyverse')
df <- read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zloniko/ca9d6e8d143dfa4f6cb163244b4ac819/raw/9298fb728726de4d55cd7dc44518581a863a855a/drugs.csv')
coxph(Surv(time = df$TOD) ~ (Concentration+DrugType):CloneType, data = df)
```

In the output I have:

```
                                coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z        p
Concentration:CloneTypegreen 0.36670   1.44297  0.03702  9.905  < 2e-16
Concentration:CloneTypered   0.34919   1.41792  0.03179 10.983  < 2e-16
.......................................................................
```

Am I correct and `green` and `red` clones have different sensitivity to a drug?

In case it is so could you help me to find the effect size and visualize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with the way you've set up this model. (I'm assuming that all samples of all clones under all treatments eventually died. Otherwise your `Surv()` object needs to have a censoring indicator, not just a death time.)

First, you seem to have coded `Concentration` as a continuous predictor having a linear association with log-hazard of death. Effects of drugs often are expressed better on a logarithmic scale of concentration, providing an approximately linear association over a reasonable range of concentrations. You need to verify your linearity assumption. It might be OK, but you need to check it.

Second, your model term `(Concentration+DrugType)` has an implicit assumption that `Concentration` and `DrugType` have additive effects on log-hazard. That is, you're assuming that the slope of the concentration-survival relationship is identical for all values of `Drug`. Again, might be true, but you need to verify.

Third, your use of the `:` operator between that additive term and `CloneType` doesn't provide a direct test of the *difference* between the `red` and `green` types. The way you've set up the model, the `Concentration:CloneTypegreen` and `Concentration:CloneTypered` coefficients you show just represent the slopes of the concentration-outcome relationships separately for `green` and `red` clones. Both those concentration-outcome slopes are significantly different from 0. But your model doesn't provide a comparison of concentration-outcome slope *difference* between the two levels of `CloneType`. At first glance, the slopes don't seem significantly different at all. But with the limitations noted above with respect to the handling of `Concentration` itself and its additivity with `Drug`, it's premature to say for sure.

What you've done is set up a model that only includes interaction terms, without any individual terms. As the discussion on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11009/28500) describes, that's almost never a good idea.

Putting aside the `Drug` term for now and assuming that you have `Concentration` properly transformed to have a linear association with log-hazard of death, the most straightforward way to test for a difference with respect to `CloneType` is to include both individual effects and an interaction for `Concentration` and `CloneType`. Written out fully, that would be:

```
coxph(Surv(time = df$TOD) ~ Concentration + CloneType + Concentration:CloneType, data = df)
```

but R will generate that directly from:

```
coxph(Surv(time = df$TOD) ~ Concentration * CloneType, data = df).
```

Then the coefficient for `Concentration` will be the concentration-outcome slope for the reference `CloneType` (apparently `green`), that for `CloneType` will be the difference associated with `red` versus `green` when `Concentration` is 0, and the `Concentration:CloneTypered` coefficient will be the *difference* in concentration-response slope for `red` versus `green`. That *difference* in slopes is what you seem to be interested in, so it's the significance of the interaction term *in this full model* that you need to examine. (If you are examining different drugs, then add appropriate individual and interaction terms based on your understanding of the subject matter and the specific hypotheses you wish to test.)

Finally, consider whether survival analysis is really the best measure of drug sensitivity. Survival analysis will tell you how *quickly* drugs kill the cells, but drug sensitivity is more typically defined as the drug concentration at which half of cells have been killed at some defined time (IC50). Consider what those reviewing and reading your work will be expecting in your field of study. If survival analysis isn't what they expect as a measure of "drug sensitivity" be prepared to defend you choice if you continue to use it.