# Multivariate regression without all interaction variables

Tags: regression, interaction, regression-coefficients

sorry if this is a total newbie question,but can I run the following regression formula:
Y= X1 + X2 + X3 + X1* X2 +X1* X3
without adding upper level interaction variables, such as X1 * X2 *X3?

Thanks

Comment: This is *multiple* regression, not "multivariate." The latter is the case of two or more *response* variables $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ analyzed simultaneously. BTW, a useful thought experiment is to consider a dataset with a fairly large number $k$ of predictors $X_i.$ If you were to insist on including *all* interactions, right through the $k$-way interaction, you would have to estimate $2^k-1$ coefficients, therefore requiring *at least* $2^k$ observations. For instance, with just a modest $k=50,$ how many studies do you suppose could afford to make $2^{50}\gt10^{15}$ = one quadrillion observations?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's perfectly acceptable. It's usually best to base you model on your understanding of the subject matter. If your understanding of the subject matter indicates that only the `X1:X2` and `X1:X3` interaction are likely to be important, that would generally be OK. Certainly there is no rule in statistics against doing that. There can be a problem when you include interactions and omit individual terms for the predictors, however, as discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11009/28500).

As you are just starting to learn about this, recognize that there is a tradeoff that involves the art of statistical modeling.

It can be best to start with as complex a model as possible that won't overfit your data. See Section 4.1 of Frank Harrell's [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) or [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/). That could involve several levels of interactions, flexible modeling of continuous predictors, etc. If you have a very large data set, that can be a more productive approach, particularly if your interest is in prediction.

With a more complex model and a limited data set, however, you run risks of overfitting and finding spurious "significant" effects or, as you have to estimate more coefficients from your data with a complex model, losing power to find truly significant effects. With that in mind, only you and your colleagues can weight the benefits against the risks of a more complex model in any particular circumstance. Harrell's course notes and book provide useful guidance on this.