# Interaction analysis using regression model

Tags: r, regression

I'm interested in finding the interaction impact of 3 genes together on a quantitative phenotype with adjustment of 3 covariates . I want to study the interaction effect but not the main effect. I'm fitting this model:

```
model<-lm(quantitative trait~ covariate 1+ covariate 2+ covariate 3+gene1:gene2:gene3,data)
```

So my questions are:
Is it correct to look at the interaction effect without looking at the main effect?
Is the model correct?
Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: Please look at [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11009/28500) and see if you still think it’s reasonable to omit “main effects” or the two-way interactions. If so, please edit your question to clarify what you hope to gain by doing so. I suspect that the scientific question will require including all those lower-level terms.