# Significant Difference between two linear regression models

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova

I'm trying to predict `weight` based of `age` and `height` for people under 30 and people 30+

I have the original data set `mydata`

I have then created two subsets `mydatalessthan30` and `mydata30plus`

Then I have

`A = lm(mydatalessthan30$weight ~ mydatalessthan30$age + mydatalessthan30$height)`

`B = lm(mydata30plus$weight ~ mydata30plus$age + mydata30plus$height)`

I then want to check if there is a significant difference between the models, how should I do this?

I have tried Anova(A,B) but this doesn't work

Answer (score 8):

I think `anova(A, B)` is not meaningful here since you are comparing models fitted to different datasets.

It seems to me that you are asking whether weight responds differently in people < 30 year-old vs people > 30 year-old while taking height into account. If so, you want to assess the effect of interaction between height and age, like:

```
fit <- lm(weight ~ age * height, data=mydata)
summary(fit)
```

where `age` is a dichotomous variable with two levels (<30, >30). That is, you are asking: how different is the slope of the regression line of height vs weight in <30 compared to the slope of height vs weight in >30?

As an aside, I wonder whether you actually need to dichotomize age since in doing so you reduce the information contained in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [dariober's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/594236/171783)(*), I think it would be better to check if a first order effect of `age` on `weight` is present.

```
fit1 <- lm(weight ~ height, mydata)
fit2 <- lm(weight ~ age + height, mydata)

summary(fit2)
anova(fit1, fit2)
```

Without 1st order effects, don't try to find 2nd order ones. If any are found, they are spurious findings. But if there are reasons to believe that `age` has an effect on `weight` fit a model with the second order, interaction `age*height`.

```
fit3 <- lm(weight ~ age * height, mydata)

anova(fit1, fit3)  # redundant
anova(fit2, fit3)  # this is the one you want.
```

---

(*) The last sentence alone deserves an extra upvote.

Comment: "Without 1st order effects, don't try to find 2nd order ones. If any are found, they are spurious findings." Can you substantiate this claim? I have dealt with quite a few real-world datasets where that was simply wrong. For some of them it was even expected from scientific theory that the main effect would be zero and only an interaction would exist. I would certainly start (and stop) with the full model in this specific example based on what is already known about these relationships.

Comment: @Roland [Related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11009/including-the-interaction-but-not-the-main-effects-in-a-model). Taller people tend to be heavier, older people tend to gain weight. But if older people do not tend to gain weight, without a main effect, what can an interaction between age and height represent other than a spurious effect? Age is not nested in height.

Comment: If you include an interaction, you should include all lower-order effects, yes. (Exceptions exist.) But you are saying something different. I do not agree that you should not include an interaction if a main effect is not significant.