# Interpretation of coefficient on an interaction term of log(continuos x)*log(continuous y)

Tags: regression, interaction, interpretation, logarithm

I would like to ask a question regarding the interpretation of log-log interaction term in the Two-way fixed effect model. I have the following regression model:

y_it = _0 + 2[ln(price_it)*ln(area_it)] + myu_i + phi_t + u_it

here, y is years of schooling (continuous), price is housing price (continuous), and area is house size.

If 2 is 0.5, then how can I interpret point estimate **in the logarithm setting**?

For example, 1% change in house price and 1% change in house area at the same time leads to 0.5 more years of schooling?

I am not familiar with the log*log interpretation here and would like to get some help!

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: There's nothing special, because logarithms are just numbers.  [Search our site for many, many answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=log+regression+interpret*+answers%3A1+score%3A1).

Comment: There's a potential problem, as this seems to include a product of two predictors in an interaction without including the predictors individually. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11009/28500) for why that's not usually a good idea.