# Cox regression with two-way interaction and interaction p value

Tags: r, survival, p-value, interaction, cox-model

Hi I am using Cox regression to do some survival analysis.
I have one continous predictor variable called "biomarker" and two binary categorical variables sex and diabetes.

I want to get the interaction p-values between sex and "biomarker", in both non-diabetics and diabetic patients.

I am currently using the following code:

```
coxph(
  Surv(days2death, death) ~ 
  factor(diabetes) :
    (factor(male)  * biomarker) +
    factor(diabetes), data = df.cox.testing).
```

Am I correct in thinking that the last two rows correspond to interaction p-values between biomarker and sex at different levels of diabetes?

```
                                                 coef exp(coef)  se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)
factor(diabetes)1                         -1.682469  0.185914  1.116110 -1.507    0.132
factor(diabetes)0:factor(male)1           -0.168605  0.844842  0.879000 -0.192    0.848
factor(diabetes)1:factor(male)1           -0.271691  0.762089  1.013834 -0.268    0.789
factor(diabetes)0:biomarker                0.108440  1.114538  0.130682  0.830    0.407
factor(diabetes)1:biomarker                0.224785  1.252054  0.145329  1.547    0.122
factor(diabetes)0:factor(male)1:biomarker -0.045544  0.955477  0.168073 -0.271    0.786
factor(diabetes)1:factor(male)1:biomarker -0.008174  0.991859  0.166480 -0.049    0.961
```

I created a forest plot with the results. However the overlap of the confidence intervals doesnt seem to fit visually with the extracted p-values. (Blue is female, red is male)

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason why you omitted `male` as a predictor in its own right, outside of the interaction? It can be confusing to interpret interactions when one of the included predictors doesn't have its own term in the model.

Comment: No I just prefer the output more, when including only the variable that I want to stratify for (here diabetes) as a predictor. When I do the same for ```male``` it does not change anything about the model/output/p-values. But I can see how that can be confusing.

Comment: Please look at [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11009/28500). You shouldn't choose a model based on how its initial summary report of coefficient values looks. You can always use post-modeling tools (e.g, those in the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans), or those built in to the [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) for its own functions, to make any comparisons or display that you want from the correct model.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: First, R in general puts interactions on the bottom of these tables (and higher order actions below lower order, if you have them) and second, the fact that two variables are listed on those lines (along with the value of the categorical variable) should tell you that.

Comment: I did not want to open a seperate thread but I have edited my post.