# p-values different for binomial test vs. proportions test. Which to report?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, p-value, proportion

The following binomial test (exact binomial test) has a *p*-value of **0.05698**, greater than 0.05 by a bit. 95% CI is (0.5698, 0.8077).

```
binom.test(x = 44, n = 63, p = 0.8, alternative = "two.sided")
```

The following proportions test (without Yates' continuity correction) has a *p*-value of **0.04382**, less than 0.05 by a bit. 95% CI is (0.5764, 0.7976).

```
prop.test(x = x1, n = n1, p = 0.8, alternative = "two.sided", correct = FALSE)
```

So, which test should I choose? Which *p*-value to report? Thanks.

Comment: Please tell us what hypothesis you are testing. Also fix a mistake: "less" and "greater" are flipped.

Comment: Thanks @Harvey Motulsky for pointing out the typos. I wish to test H0: p=0.8 vs Ha: p <> 0.8, at alpha = 0.05. BTW, your _Intuitive Biostatistics_ is a great book!

Comment: The answer you're looking for probably manifests from the underlying reasons why the proportions test is "approximate" and the binomial test is "exact."

Comment: Thanks @ndoogan, @Harvey. Does this mean that the binomial test (exact binomial test) is **always preferred** to the normal approximation in `prop.test()`? Some textbooks say that when the sample size $n$ is large, the binomial distribution is **cumbersome** to work with, and the normal approximation can be considerably **more convenient**. I guess such textbooks are saying so in the context of pen-and-paper calculations? With computers, is there still a need to do such approximations?

Comment: If a well-considered significance test is part of your strategy, and if you are in doubt as to whether one type of test is more applicable than the other, best practice is to report results from both so as not to give the appearance of cherry-picking.  As to the "well considered" part, I recommend http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/what-are-good-references-containing-arguments-against-null-hypothesis-significan.

Comment: @DanWu, you’re right that the binomial test is more cumbersome to work with for large *n*, but this only true if you’re calculating the results *by hand*. As long as you use R, there is no problem. And for large *n* it doesn’t matter, as both functions give approximately the same answer. But do note that `prop.test()` uses the score test, *not* a Wald test (which I guess is what the textbooks were talking about). Anyway, in practice, there is no reason not to use `binom.test()`, as this always gives exact *P*-values.

Answer (score 6):

If you are testing whether 44 occurrences out of 63 can be a sample from the binomial population with probability 80% of a success in individual independent trial, then the first test is certainly correct.

Comment: ... as long as the Bernoulli assumptions hold -- independence, constant probability of success.

Comment: Hi @Germaniawerks, I used `prop.test` in the context of normal approximation to the binomial distribution, by the rule of thumb that $np$ and $n(1 − p)$ are both greater than 5.